# RewriteRule doesn't work in ubuntu 14.04 How can I fix it?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

This is my `.htaccess` code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

but the `RewriteRule` doesn't work.

I am using `VMware` and have installed `Ubuntu` verion xamp with `mod-rewrite`.

I saw other post with similar problems, but those didn't solve my problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is not working, provide more details.

Comment: I Dont know why..  I have 404 error  server cant find my page

Comment: Are you able to access your pages without the `.htaccess` file? Can you access your css/js files that are ignored by these rules?

Comment: I install mod-rewirte by `a2enmod rewrite` after that `service apache2 restart`

Comment: @Lix yes, this code worked in windows xamp  and  linux host but when I used  in localhost ubuntu dosent work

Comment: @Sdfarshidmousavi - that is not what I asked. **Can you access your css/js files that are ignored by these rules?**

Comment: @lix YES , I Can Access my css/js, just `RewriteRule ` doesnt work

Comment: Did you change the `AllowOverride` to `ALL` in file apache2.conf?

Comment: @iatboy i change the `AllowOverride ` To All

Comment: What is your `DpcumentRoot` and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava my `DCRoot` and `htaccess ` located in var/www

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: @anubhava `.htaccess` is enabled . `RewriteCond` dose work , just `RewriteRule` doesnt work,

Comment: DId you run my verification test?

Comment: @anubhava i put a random text on top of my htaccess but I didnt see 500 internal server error

Comment: @Sdfarshidmousavi then try reinstalling mod_rewrite again

Comment: That is the reason I wanted you to verify it but you kept saying **.htaccess is enabled**

Comment: Even if it was enabled it would still not work with his current rule either way

Comment: I thank all the friends ,I had  problem  in apache2.conf AccesFileName .htacces was wrong  my `htaccess` doesnt hide but i used .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava Thank you your guide was so mind

Comment: isn't the rule written: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L, QSA]` ? I dk... I'm just asking... :D